# Does a non-Bean Managed Property NOT update in Target Bean with change in the Property in Source Bean in JSF? The same may also be true vice-versa

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using a property inside one bean as a Managed Property inside another.

The problem I'm facing is with change of the property inside the source bean, the target bean's Managed Property is **NOT** getting updated. If Java uses referencing instead of creating new object in the memory, this shouldn't be happening, but it is.

Both my beans are session-scoped. Does that affect the injection of the property? Does that mean change in view does **NOT** initialize the injection if the beans are session-scoped? Even then, it goes against the referencing idea user BalusC has made in the comment of this answer.

[How to get managedbean property from another bean in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004309/how-to-get-managedbean-property-from-another-bean-in-jsf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're referencing the target bean's property directly instead of the target bean itself.

The below is indeed wrong:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{otherBean.property}")
private String otherBeanProperty;
```

`String` is immutable and you're basically copying the property. This isn't mutable by reference.

Instead you should be doing:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{otherBean}")
private OtherBean otherBean;
```

and then obtain the desired property by its getter in any of the source bean's methods.

Comment: You're welcome. You're right, I edited and clarified the referenced answer.